# Hide button based on containing text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to hide a button containing the text 'Buy Now' using jQuery. This button is within a containing div.

Basically something like this:

```
$("button contains('Buy Now').parent('div').hide();
```

Answer (score 6):

You mean this:

API: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Hope it fits the cause, `:)` **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/DDv8a/ try this **demo**

**code**

```
$("button:contains('Buy Now')").parent('div').hide();
```

**or**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[value='Buy Now']").closest('div').hide();
});
```

​

Comment: lol @Hogan I will buy you a pint and best coffee in the world - also `:)` this favour will be remembered bruv `:)` and shall be returned with awesomeness!

Comment: Yo yo @Raminson < Boom > and here is your entry for today!! `:)` howsz things

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Wassup bruv, howz life innit! indeed seems like `:)`

Comment: With a rep like that, you might hit 9,999 - that gets briefly annoying ;-)

Comment: @Neil yeah I really need to take that screen shot of 9999 `:)` it will go into my wall, 'n you will be shout-ed with a cup of kopi luak :) if we ever met!

Comment: @Tats_innit Nope still not working, my body looks like this, not sure if I've missed something: <body>
<div class="prod_buy">
<input name="Add to Cart" type="submit" class="rb green txtbutton" value="Buy Now">
</div>
</body>